# Relationship between block, controller and model - magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new guy to magento. I have seen `$this->functionName()` in `template file` of particular module. And then functionName() is placed under `block`. My question is Can I call any `controller` function or `model` function from `block`? Any relationship between block with controller and model?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but may be, this might help for calling model from block

```
public function getTagInfo()
{
    if (is_null($this->_tagInfo)) {
        $this->_tagInfo = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')
            ->load($this->getTagId());
    }
    return $this->_tagInfo;
}
```

Regarding Controller:
Controller's job is to do certain things to Models, and then tell the system it's layout rendering time. That's it. It's your Layout/Blocks job to display an HTML page in a certain way depending on the state of the system's Models.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I understood importance of controller. But one doubt is load($this->getTagId() function is written inside tag/Model/Tag.php ?

Comment: This link might help you for models
http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm

Answer (score 0):

**Block** Responsible for rendering content (everything from frontend, backend, emails, and more).

**Controller**
Responsible for handling Http Requests and contain business logic. A controller usually interacts with Models. Controllers can implement one of the following interfaces `HttpGetActionInterface`, `HttpPutActionInterface`, `HttpPostActionInterface`, `HttpDeleteActionInterface`, etc. which gives context of what a controller is supposed to do with the data it receives.

**Model** `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` Represents a data object. For example an User, Product or Category. They contain getters and setters so that a controller knows what data it can use.

**ResourceModel** `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`
Is used to provide a database resource like MySQL for your Model to interact with the database. The ResourceModel in Magento requires a table name and id of the primary key.

**Collection** `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection` Allows you to retrieve collections of your Models. A collection requires both the Model and ResourceModel.